# Display Leave table output in customized format

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server query required: I have a `Leave` table as shown here; I want to get result as mentioned in required output format.

`Leave` table:

| EMP_ID | From_date | To_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 02-01-2023 | 05-01-2023 |
| 1 | 16-01-2023 | 19-01-2023 |
| 2 | 03-01-2023 | 03-01-2023 |

Required output

| EMP_ID | Leave_Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 02-01-2023 |
| 1 | 03-01-2023 |
| 1 | 04-01-2023 |
| 1 | 05-01-2023 |
| 1 | 16-01-2023 |
| 1 | 17-01-2023 |
| 1 | 18-01-2023 |
| 1 | 19-01-2023 |
| 2 | 03-01-2023 |

Thanks in advance

I tried in different ways but with no luck

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: SELECT Range = DATEADD(DAY, InitialDate, num.N) FROM Ta cc JOIN FNTALLY(0, 333) num ON num.N < DATEDIFF(DAY, InitialDate,  EndDate) . 333 = max difference between those 2

Comment: FNTALLY https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/create-a-tally-function-fntally

Answer (score 0):

You can join an ad-hoc numbers table

Note that I used `Select Top 1000 ...`, you can adjust to a more reasonable number.

**Example**

```
Select A.[EMP_ID]
      ,LeavDate = dateadd(DAY,N,[From_date])
 From  YourTable A
 Join ( Select Top 1000 N=-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) From master..spt_values n1, master..spt_values n2 ) B
   on N<=datediff(day,[From_date],[To_Date])
 Order by A.[EMP_ID],B.N
```

**Results**

```
EMP_ID  LeavDate
1       2023-01-02
1       2023-01-16
1       2023-01-03
1       2023-01-17
1       2023-01-04
1       2023-01-18
1       2023-01-05
1       2023-01-19
2       2023-01-03
```

Comment: SELECT ... FROM Ta x CROSS JOIN FNTALLY

Comment: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/create-a-tally-function-fntally

Comment: @BogdanSahlean  CROSS JOIN is not what OP was looking for.   It would explode the dataset.   And don't you think that tally function is a overkill ?  The ad-hoc is shockingly performant and can be tuned.